# If This Then That (IFTTT) preserve whitespace RSS feed

Tags: rss, if-this-then-that, xml

Can anyone help me out with a method to preserve white space/line breaks in an RSS-feed-to-email IFTTT task?

I have tried using `xml:space="preserve"`, `<![CDATA[ <br> ]]>` and just plain `<br>` but when I use any of these methods, it seems to break the task and I stop receiving the emails.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I have a feed setup that posts to tumblr and I've never had issues with spacing.

Looking at it seems to be that the `<p>` and `<br \>` tags are respected by `ifttt`.

Here's snippet (note, it's a vent anonymously site so I'm trying to find a safe one). This is from the `<content:encoded>` section of a wordpress xml feed

`<content:encoded>
    <![CDATA[
    <p>I am so tired. My head hurts and it feels like it is going to literally explode at any moment. I am so pissed off.<br /> They keep asking me to do everything, despite the fact I don&#8217;t have time. I need to sleep, I need to rest, i need to actually do my works for uni. And instead they keep ordering me to go around solving all their problems. They are the parents, they are supposed to me the ones to take responsability, not me. When am I going to start living my own life. it&#8217;s like I&#8217;m just a tool they can use whenever they need it. I am a person, not a tool. </p>
    ]]>
    </content:encoded>`